# Comparator function in Priority Queue

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand how the comparator function return value determines which element goes before the other when inserting into a Priority Queue.

Below code stores integers in the descending order based on a comparator function.
I understand that I do not need a comparator function for this simple evaluation, but its easier to visualize with simple data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

struct Compfunc {
    bool operator() (const int &a, const int &b) {
        //cout << "a: " << a << " vs b: " << b << endl;
        return (a < b);
    }
};

void callPQ(vector<int> &vec) {
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, Compfunc> pq;
    
    for (auto num : vec) {
        cout << "Pushing : " << num << endl;
        pq.push(num);
    }

    cout << "Printing:" << endl;
    while (!pq.empty()) {
        cout << pq.top() << endl;
        pq.pop();
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec{5, 6, 4, 9, 2, 0};
    
    callPQ(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

Output,

```
Pushing : 5
Pushing : 6
Pushing : 4
Pushing : 9
Pushing : 2
Pushing : 0
Printing:
9
6
5
4
2
0
```

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/

> The expression comp(a,b), where comp is an object of this type and a and b are elements in the container, shall return true if a is considered to go before b in the strict weak ordering the function defines.

Is the following observation correct?

1. Whenever an entry is pushed into `pq`, does it **always** become `b` element in `compfunc`?
2. If (1) is correct, then when I push `6` in `pq`, `a = 5` and `b = 6`. And the return is `true` i.e., `5 < 6`, meaning that `5` goes before `6` in `pq`, but in fact `6` should become the `top` of `pq`.

I'm puzzled on (2) and how the `Compfunc` comparison works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Whenever an entry is pushed into pq, does it always become b element in compfunc?

No, that is entirely implementation defined.

What the standard guarantees is that the elements in the `priority_queue` are sorted in descending order, where the "*order*" is defined by the `Compfunc` compare function being used. In order to deliver that promise, the implementation will call `Compfunc` as many times as necessary during each `push`, and with whatever arguments it sees fit. Neither the number of the calls nor the arguments in each call are mandated or specified by the standard.

> 2. If (1) is correct, then when I push 6 in pq, a = 5 and b = 6. And the return is true i.e., 5 < 6, meaning that 5 goes before 6 in pq, but in fact 6 should become the top of pq.

The default compare function for a `priority_queue` is `std::less`, which coincides with the natural order for numeric types. For example, `5, 6, 4, 9, 2, 0` sorts as `0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9` in ascending order. Therefore the `priority_queue` will have the largest element `9` at the top, and then `6, 5, 4, 2, 0` following in descending order.

One of the examples at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue shows how to create a `priority_queue` in the reverse order, with the lowest elements at the top, by using `std::greater` as the compare function, instead of the default `std::less`.

Comment: So when using a ```Compfunc``` to order the elements in a descending manner, the return should always be ```a < b```? Would it remain the same for a more complex data e.g., ```a.second < b.second```

Comment: @adizone In this context, saying that `a < b` is the same as saying that `Compfunc(a, b) == true`. `Compfunc` is what *defines* the order, and this is true even for complex or composite types which may not necessarily have an intuitive or unique "less than" ordering. For your example, having `Compfunc` return  `a.second < b.second` means that the priority queue will have the element with the largest `second` value at the top.

Answer (score 3):

1. When and with what parameters the comparator is called depends on the implementation alone.
2. https://en.cppreference.com/ is a bit more detailed and more precise than the reference you used. It states about the [comparator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

   > Note that the Compare parameter is defined such that it returns true if its first argument comes before its second argument in a weak ordering. But because the priority queue outputs largest elements first, the elements that "come before" are actually output last. That is, the front of the queue contains the "last" element according to the weak ordering imposed by Compare.

   I hope this answers your question(s).

Comment: Thanks for pointing the description. In this case, the ```front``` does not mean the ```top``` of the queue i.e., ```pq.top()```?